# Could not find conda environment: python_cvcourse

Tags: python-3.x, conda, opencv, python

I had problems with installing the libaries file at first so after installing anaconda I uninstalled everything and did a fresh install.

When I did that, I installed all the libraries with the command `conda env create –f cvcourse_windows.yml`  and everything went well. After that I typed `conda activate python_cvcourse`  and this is what happened

[image]

Now I am not sure what happened, am I missing a file in my downloads? Here is the pic of my files in my downloads

[image]

I tried

[image]

Now I cant run the packaget in Jupyer because I cannot load the libraries. How do I find the python_cvcourse?

Thanks

Aleksej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the environment is `python-cvcourse` with a hyphen (-), not `python_cvcourse` with an underscore (_).